# Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm playing around with a simple universal app. I tried accessing phones geolocation. According to MSDN, before accessing device location you ought to call `Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync` static method. The thing is... There is no such static method available... Only `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals` static methods are. Not event return value enumeration `GeolocationAccessStatus` exists.

I tried accessing geolocation without calling this method and it works on emulator. But on a real phone is a different story...

.NET Framework I'm using is 4.5.3, although I don't see any specific requirement for this method/class. Checking "Location" under "Capabilities" also does nothing. Plus, I can easily create a new instance of `Geolocator` object and use it's methods.

I bet its something something very easy/stupid, I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Fooled me too, it is only part of Universal apps - Windows 10.

For Win 8.1 if you install the app then turn the location off, then run the app you may need this code to achieve the same result as RequestAccessAsync().

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();

            try
            {
                geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                    maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Location not allowed by user phone setting
                if (ex.HResult == -2147024891)
                {
                    ... LocationNotAuthorized
                }

                ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the documentation has been updated for Windows 10, but in doing so it has lost information for Windows (Phone) 8.1. Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't require the use of `RequestAccessAsync` because consent is granted at the time the user installs the app from the Store.

Comment: So the reason for `geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()` method never finishing on my phone is probably different? Is it normal for debug application to never ask for location retrieval permission (because I do not recall receiving it)?